# Complex model relationships in django

Tags: sql, django, relationship

My question is how can i design my db scheme easier?

I have three models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name')
    tasklists = models.ManyToManyField(Tasklist)

class Tasklist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name')

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField('Name')
    tasklist = models.ForeignKey(Tasklist)
```

So, idea is that i have a project, that may have many task lists (and in each task list may be several tasks). Also, the same task list may refer to several projects with the same tasks.

But what i need is to save the state of a task for a particular project. So, let's say, i have two projects, which have the same basic task list with two tasks, but in first project i have done all tasks already, but not in second. Where should i store the state of a task, specific for each project?
Thanks for help in advance!

Project 1 --> Basic TaskList --> Task 1 (done) Task 2 (done)
Project 2 --> Basic TaskList --> Task 1 (active) Task 2 (active)

My guess is to create another model like this:

```
class TaskState(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is probably a way to go, don't think you can avoid an extra table.

You are basically declaring a new many-to-many relationship with an extra field, so you can declare it as such, [see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

```
class Project(models.Model):
    task_states = models.ManyToManyField(Task, through='TaskState')
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding this extra field really simplifies querying.

Answer (score 2):

Here you want to save relationship state of Many to Many database. This is a textbook case and your solution is the best way to handle such situation. This will allow you to have other fields corresponding to this relation in future. Following are the standard practices to record relationship states:

- One to One relation: Move the relationship state to either of the table
- One to Many relation: Move the relationship state to table of multiple instances
- Many to Many relation: Create a new table have primary key as combination of both table's primary key and have relationship information as fields